# Why is a pointer to NULL-charater not converted to false

Tags: c++, pointers

I thought the pointer pointed to `NULL` can be converted to `0`. So I wrote the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

bool is_strtoi(const std::string& str)
{
    char *p;
    std::strtol(str.c_str(), &p, 10);
    return *p == '\0';
}

bool is_strtoi1(const std::string& str)
{
    char *p;
    std::strtol(str.c_str(), &p, 10);
    return p; //Pointer to NULL should be converted to false;
}

int main ()
{
    std::string test1("123asd2");
    std::string test2("123123");
    std::cout << is_strtoi1(test1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_strtoi1(test2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_strtoi(test1) << std::endl; //prints 1
    std::cout << is_strtoi(test2) << std::endl;
}
```

Accroding to the 4.12 section of the Standard:

> A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is
>   converted to false

So why it didn't?

Comment: I don't see a single null pointer anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're a layer of indirection out! A "null pointer" and "a pointer to null/zero" are two different things.

At its most basic:

- A null pointer itself has the value zero.
- It doesn't point to some other object with the value zero.

```
p  == 0;  // yes
*p == 0;  // no
```

Indeed, a `char*` pointing to a C-string of length 0 (i.e. `{'\0'}`) is not a null pointer; it is a perfectly valid pointer.

Going further, though, the notion that a pointer can "have the value zero" is actually an implementation detail. In abstract terms, *pointers are not numbers* and so we shall not consider a null pointer to have a numerical value such as zero. This is evident in the introduction of the `nullptr` keyword that cannot be implicitly converted to an integer. By removing the whole discussion about "zero", we can instead give the following improved, more appropriate example:

```
p  == nullptr; // yes
*p == '\0';    // no
```

Comment: "A null pointer itself has the value zero" = probably true, but you aren't supposed to believe that anymore. p!=nullptr is safer

Comment: @MartinBeckett: Clarified

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
bool is_strtoi1(const std::string& str)
{
    char *p;
    std::strtol(str.c_str(), &p, 10);
    return p; //Pointer to NULL should be converted to false;
}
```

will ONLY EVER return `false`  if the address in `p` is `NULL`. It is guaranteed to NOT be `NULL` if the input string to `strtol` is not `NULL` [which isn't going to happen for `std::string` in any well-behaved program - and input of `NULL` to `strtol` is undefined behaviour, so it's not defined what happens to `p` in that case - but it's likely that you get a crash from such an attempt].

In other words, your premise for converting to `bool` is incorrect.

You could write it as:

```
 return *p;
```

which will return true if `p` points at a nul (zero) character.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mixing up "null pointer" with "pointer to NULL" (whatever the latter means). The standard text you quoted does not say anything about any "pointers to NULL". The text you quoted says clearly and explicitly that *null pointer* is converted to `false`.

The code you posted does not have any null pointers, i.e. it does not have any pointers with null pointer value. Pointer `p` in your code points to some valid location inside the `str.c_str()` buffer, which means that `p` itself is not null. Hence there's nothing in your code that would be converted to `false` per the quoted passage form the standard.